# Simple question about Liouville formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Liouville Formula**

> $\det X(t)=\det X(t_0)\exp\left( \int^t_{t_0}tr A(u) du\right)$

Why when $t_0=0$ we have $\det e^{tA}=e^{t(trA)}$

My book says this, but I couldn't understand why.

I need help.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably $X$ is the solution to the ODE $\dot{X} = A(t) X$, subject to a specified initial condition at $t_0$.

If $X(0) = I$, and $A$ is a constant (that is, not time dependent), then we have $X(t) = e^{At}$.

Liouville's Formula gives $\det X(t) = \det e^{At} = (\det I) e^{\int_0^t \operatorname{tr} A d\tau} = e^{t\operatorname{tr} A }$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us prove the formula for $t_0=0$. Let $X=AYA^{-1}$, where $Y$ is an upper triangular matrix and $A\in GL_n(\mathbb C)$ (this decomposition is always possible). Then, if $Y$ has diagonal elements $(y_1,\dots,y_n)$, the product $Y^{k}$ has diagonal elements $(y^k_1,\dots,y^k_n)$, by induction.

As

$$\exp(AYA^{-1})=A\exp(Y)A^{-1},$$

then $\exp(Y)$ is an upper triangular matrix with diagonal elements $(\exp(y_1),\dots,\exp(y_n))$. We arrive at

$$ det(\exp(Y))=e^{y_1}\cdot\dots\cdot e^{y_n}=e^{y_1+\dots+y_n}=e^{tr(Y)}.$$

In summary

$$det(\exp(AYA^{-1}))=det(A\exp(Y)A^{-1})=det(\exp(Y))=e^{tr(Y)}. $$